# Ubuntu does not run on the Nexus 7

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

After "Preparing mouth file system", the screensaver Ubuntu Nexus have a black screen. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and am starting the whole process again.

This is what I'm doing differently:
Make sure you don't run the installer 2x by accident (I don't remember running it twice, but apparently I did).
Make sure you give it enough time to finish unpacking (10-20min).

I hope this works :)